# Own domain address on Azure DNS

Tags: azure, dns

Can i have my own DNS Server Address on "Azure DNS" like ns1.mydomain.com?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that i can't do that yet. I have to use Azure's DNS Server to point my domain.

There is a request in the Microsoft Feeadback. It can be voted in here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/13381482-introduce-vanity-name-servers